# Building menu or ComboBox with data stocked in a "dynamic" array

Tags: javascript, arrays, extjs, combobox

I want to add a comboBox or menu button to my interface which will have data in it that comes from an array. The data in the array won't always be the same so I need the button to be "dynamic". How can I achieve that ? I can't specify a model if the array changes...

Edit: I'm using ExtJS 6, so I need to be able to feed the menu parameter:

```
 menu: [{
     text:'Menu Item 1'
   },{
     text:'Menu Item 2'
   },{
     text:'Menu Item 3'
 }]
```

Example:

1) Users selects a menu item and click on a send button.

2) Depending on the value of the item the user clicked on, a javascript array is created with sometimes 2, sometimes 10 fields in it.

3) The fields are shown in a new menu button or combobox.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="example" list="exampleList">
<datalist id="exampleList">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
</datalist>
```

Javascript

```
function generateOptionsFromDynamicArray (arr) {
    // Get the datalist by id, cache option variable
    var datalist = document.querySelector('#exampleList'),
        option;
    // Remove old options
    while( datalist.firstChild ) {
        datalist.removeChild(datalist.firstChild);
    }
    // Loop through array
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; ++i) {
        option = document.createElement('option');
        option.setAttribute('value', arr[i]);
        option.innerText = arr[i];
        datalist.appendChild(option);
    }
}
```

I created a function that you can pass that dynamic array into in order to update the combobox, in this case I'm using a datalist. 
A few points about this code, you should add a check to ensure arr is an array or "array-like" (typedarrays I'm looking at you). You should also remove the datalist from the DOM while these changes are happening so you dont redraw the DOM on each iteration

I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0uqfv0f/) for testing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I forgot to specify that I'm using ExtJS to create my buttons and interface. I will update my question regarding that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot listen to an array `change` event, so whenever you change the array, you would also have to call following function:

```
function arrayToStore(array) {
    var store = Ext.getCmp("myComboId").getStore();
    //var store = Ext.getStore("myComboStore");
    store.removeAll();
    store.add(array.map(function(item) {
        // This maps the array entry into a model you can add to the store. 
        // Instead of "field1", use your field name.
        // If your array contains an object, you can preprocess it here.
        // "field1" would be the default value if you have defined 
        // an implicit store by providing an array in the combo config:
        // store:['item1','item2','item3'],
        return {
            field1:item
        };
    });
}
```